# Remove text of uitableviewcell when you are delegating two uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `uitableviewdelegate` class that is delegate of two `uitableview`. I want that one of them has remove button and the other do not have remove button. I used below code:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(tableView==self.firstTableView){
    return @"Remove";
    }else
    return @"";
}
```

button my code do not disable editing style for `secondTableView` it just set empty text as title. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I also use below methods:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(tableView == slef.FirstTableView){

     //Some codes
    }

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == self.FirstTableView){
      //Some codes
    }
}
```

but any of them was not helpful.

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on the if statement, does it ever get called by the other tableview?  In other words:  Do you ever hit the else in the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please implement this delegate method.

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (tableView==self.firstTableView) {
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Here you can return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone or UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete for desired table

Comment: you are not using the delegate method that I mentioned   -(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath